# Tracker.autorun() not executing jQuery functions

Tags: meteor

I am updating some Session variables with Router.onAfterAction whenever my route changes. Then I have a Tracker.autorun() waiting for a the change so it can run some logic and update some DOM classes. I checked the Sessions are set correctly and that the element to-be appended is targeted correctly. But my addClass() does not trigger. No console errors either. What am I missing?

```
Tracker.autorun(function (c) {

  var colActive = Session.equals('navColumnActive', true);
  var colVisible = Session.equals('navColumnVisible', true);
  var $col = $("#nav-column");
  console.log($col);


  if (colActive) {
    console.log("if triggered");
    $col.addClass( "active" );
  } else {
    console.log("else triggered");
    $col.removeClass("active");
  }
  if (colVisible) {
    $col.addClass("visible");
  } else {
    $col.removeClass("visible");
  }
});
```

Comment: I did a Meteor restart and it started working!?! I will see if I can recreate this and determine if it is my bug or a bug in Meteor and report back.

Comment: Why not use a helper to set the class on the column instead of using JQuery?

Comment: @stubailo because then it wouldn't not be exciting :)  You are right, I do not have time to debug this. Helpers to the rescue.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem just recently. In my case the reactive values triggering the computation where being executed before the DOM and the elements where properly rendered.

I would check if the session vars are being set after the DOM has been rendered. Therefore selectors like `$col = $("#nav-column")` came back empty, though perfectly worked when executed in the browser console.

You could try the following:

```
Template.<template_name>.onRendered(function() {
  Session.set('navColumnActive', true);
  Session.set('navColumnVisible', true);
})
```